# Connect phpMyAdmin with ejabberd server on ec2 ubuntu instance

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin, ejabberd

i successfully configure lamp server, phpmyadmin and ejabberd server on my ec2 Ubuntu instance. Now i want to connect my phpMyAdmin with ejabberd i don't know how to do that please provide some help or some reference. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "connect"? If you want to be able to view the database ejabberd uses in phpMyAdmin, then you just need to configure the same MySQL server for both of them and login to phpMyAdmin using either root account or the account that is used for ejabberd. What exactly is causing problems?

Answer (score 1):

change in your ejabberd configuration file-

```
## MySQL server:
##
odbc_type: mysql
odbc_server: "localhost"      #your host ip or domain name
odbc_database: "ejabberddb"   # your database name
odbc_username: "root"
odbc_password: "test"
odbc_pool_size: 50
##
## If you want to specify the port:
odbc_port: 3306
```

[for more detail check this link](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/#relational-databases)

Comment: Hi Sunil, thanks for reply i made change in config file of ejabberd but know can you please explain how can i import MySql schema i am using phpMyAdmin. Thanks

Comment: create database  in mysql for example -ejabberddb  after creating db select it and click on import button in  phpmyadmin select the sql file of ejabberd server. you can find mysql file here- https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/sql/mysql.sql